# extjs combo box selection using guid id

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am using the following to select an item in combo box.

```
var SupplierCombo = Ext.getCmp('SupplierCombo');
SupplierCombo.setValue(selection[0].data.SupplierId);
```

this is selecting the correct item in the combo however it is placing the id on the combobox as opposed to the supplier name, See screen shot. I my id field is a guid that is in string format. I wonder if this is related to my issue.

[image]

Comment: check if record corresponding to selection[0].data.SupplierId is present in the store backing  SupplierCombo. If it is, post SupplierCombo config code please. If not, thats the problem

Answer (score 0):

SupplierCombo needs to be loaded first, so please make sure that you have combo store available.

if you are trying to do setvalue and expecting that display value gets displayed on setting the value based on id, setvalue function will check if corresponding item is present in the store and if its not present it will set whatever value you are trying to set as display field. If store is not loaded in that case, you can call store load of combo, and on success handler perform the setvalue operation.

Another thing can be, that particular recode (With id 609...) doesn't exist anymore for some reason.

what happens when you click on drop down arrow? do you see other values or your correct option get selected?